# Angular- Hide button till certain conditions are met

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ng-if, angular10

I made a reactive form, where user can add data. There I have added a `add` button and a `remove` button. While clicking the `add` button user can add more input fields and remove those fields while clicking `remove`. Now I want to keep `remove` button hidden if there is only one input field. How do i do it?
The HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row ml-0" style="display: flex;">
      <span>Add custom questions:</span>
      <mat-checkbox
        style="margin-left: 10px! important;"
        (change)="selectCheck()"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="checked">
      <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 9px;"
        >NOTE : Panel members can respond with text based answers, which will be
        visible to the winner selector</span
      >
      <form [formGroup]="userForm">
        <div
          class="row"
          *ngFor="let question of getQuestionFormControls(); let i = index"
        >
          <span class="ml-3 pt-2">Question {{ i + 1 }}</span>
          <input
            class="form-control ml-3 mt-1"
            [formControl]="questions"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
        <div
          class="col mt-1 justify-content-between"
          style="display:flex;align-items:center;"
        >
          <!-- <i class="bi bi-plus-square"></i> -->
          <div class="d-flex mt-1">
            <mat-icon
              style="color: #5663ED;cursor:pointer;margin-top: 0rem;"
              (click)="addQuestion()"
              >add_box</mat-icon
            >
            <span>Add more questions</span>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex mt-1">
            <mat-icon
              (click)="removeQuestion(i)"
              style="color: #5663ED;cursor:pointer"
              >remove_circle</mat-icon
            >
            <span>Remove</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The ts code:

```
checked = false;
userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      questions: this.fb.array([this.fb.control(null)]),
    });
  }

  addQuestion(): void {
    (this.userForm.get('questions') as FormArray).push(this.fb.control(null));
  }

  removeQuestion(index) {
    (this.userForm.get('questions') as FormArray).removeAt(index);
  }

  getQuestionFormControls(): AbstractControl[] {
    return (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('questions')).controls;
  }

  selectCheck() {
    this.checked = !this.checked;
  }
```

I tried to use `*ngif="i >= 1"`  with the hopes of using the index, but it didn't work. What do I do?

A demo of the [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-4fha83?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) is the right tool; make sure you're capitalizing the "i" in "if".

Comment: *ngIf="getQuestionFormControls().length >= 1"

Comment: @Icycool I tried this and it works. But here, the remove button is visible only after the last input field. How can I make it visible with every input field? Check the link in the question for what I am trying to say

Comment: in that case you would need to put the remove button inside the ngFor

Comment: @Icycool Yeah, thanks. I am having another problem in here.  I was trying to keep the add button disabled(but still visible) till the user enters some data. How do I do it?  I tried using a `ngIf` but it only kept the button hidden till the user clicks the input field. [The link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-4fha83?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tested it, but i guess this could work fine:

```
<div 
   class="d-flex mt-1"
   *ngIf="(this.userForm.get('questions'))?.length > 1"
>
            <mat-icon
              (click)="removeQuestion(i)"
              style="color: #5663ED;cursor:pointer"
              >remove_circle</mat-icon
            >
            <span>Remove</span>
</div>
```

If it doesn't work, try to change this line:

```
*ngIf="(this.userForm.get('questions'))?.controls?.length > 1"
```

Comment: `Identifier 'length' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member` getting this error

Comment: *ngIf="(this.userForm.get('questions'))?.length > 1" need to access to value of form control like this *ngIf="this.userForm.get('questions')?.value?.length > 1"